# Find the module name of a 64 bits process from a 32 bits app

Tags: c, winapi

I am using the Win Api function GetModuleBaseName to retrieve the process name from the current window (my application is 32 bits running on Win7 64 bits):

```
HWND Handle = GetForegroundWindow();
DWORD lpdwProcessId;
HANDLE PID; 

WCHAR ProcessName[1024];
GetWindowThreadProcessId(Handle,&lpdwProcessId);
PID=OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,false,lpdwProcessId);
if (PID)
{
    if(GetModuleBaseName(PID,NULL,ProcessName,sizeof ProcessName) == 0) {
        wcscpy(ProcessName,  L"??");
        DWORD er = GetLastError();
        printf("error code: %i\n", GetLastError());
    }
}
else
{
    wcscpy(ProcessName,  L"??");
}
```

This code is working fine all 32 bits programs but not with 64 bits programs such as MSPaint where the last error returned is

```
error 299 : ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY : "Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or
WriteProcessMemory request was completed."
```

MSDN doesn't document why this particular error may happen. I read somewhere that this error can happen for the EnumProcessModulesEx due to problem between 32 and 64 bits programs, but no such thing is mentionned for GetModuleBaseName.
Is there a way to know where this is comming  from and how to fix it?

thanks

Comment: Take some moments to remove your extra indentation next time.

Comment: I don't know the answer for sure, but I suspect it will simply be necessary to use a 64-bit application for this.  If you google for `"error 299 64-bit process 32-bit app"`, you will find that a number of APIs return that error in this type of situation (32-bit app querying info from 64-bit processes).  Perhaps GetModuleBaseName uses one of those other APIs that does get that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Documentation for GetModuleBaseName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683196%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) suggests that calling GetProcessImageFileName or QueryFullProcessImageName will be more reliable than calling GetModuleBaseName with a NULL module handle.

Comment: This is indeed the case - unfortunatly, the two mentioned functions return a full path rather than a base name.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger [Path.GetFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=netframework-4.7.2) work well.